# How to find out where a function is overridden?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails project, I saw the `link_to` is overridden in `config/initializers/extend_action_view.rb`

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    def link_to(name, options = {}, html_options = nil)
    ...
    end
  end
end
```

I found that with the famous command line in linux `grep -r 'def link_to' *`.

My question is : Is there a way to find out it in `rails console` ? Is there a native function rails or ruby can give us the path of file ? Something like `.ancestors` for a object.

ps: My IDE is vi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) gem, you can find it by using `Method#source_location`.
Pass `binding.pry` in your view and render it. Then write:

```
method(:link_to).source_location
=> ["path_to_helper.rb", 124]
```

Comment: [`Method#source_location` is built-in](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Method.html#method-i-source_location). You don't need Pry to use it: `ruby -rprime -e 'p 123.method(:prime_division).source_location' # => ["/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/prime.rb", 29]`.

Comment: @Jordan, I mean use `binding.pry` to get a view instance with included app/gems helpers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$` command in `pry` gem

Insert `binding.pry` in your code, which sets a breakpoint and then in the Pry commandline use the `$` command

```
[1] pry(#<AdminController>)> $ Person.find

From: /Users/joe_example/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/composite_primary_keys-8.1.0/lib/composite_primary_keys/core.rb @ line 21:
Owner: ActiveRecord::Core::ClassMethods
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 38

def find(*ids) # :nodoc:
  # We don't have cache keys for this stuff yet
  return super unless ids.length == 1
  ...
```

The `$` command is literally worth dollars. It shows you where a method is defined as well as the source code.